# How to remove Fragment by dragging it up from its lower part?

Tags: android, android-fragments, draggable

I need to remove a fragment that comes onto screen with a custom transition from top.

This fragment contains a `ScrollView`. While the user drags the `ScrollView` I need the `ScrollView` to intercept the touches.

If the ScrollView reaches it's end and the user continues the drag, I don't need to remove the fragment in this case.

This is an illustration of the draggable layout I created (when the user touches the **red** or the **green** part the fragment should stay in place, only when he drags the **blue** part the fragment should be dragged up and finally dismissed or dismissed on fling action):

[image]

Only if the user drags the fragment at certain lower portion of it (It's bottom part) then I should drag the fragment until I remove it entirely from screen and then I should remove it from stack as well.

I tried to implement **Dragger** and **AndroidSlidingUpPanel**, but the result is not exactly as I want it. the view is dragged from all places and not only from the region I predefined and in sliding panel the view is being dismissed when the scrollview ends.

How can I achieve this behavior?

Comment: You will have to define a range to listen to dragging around only that area. But I guess you've already thought about it. If you tell us what you've done, maybe we could offer some suggestions. :)